# Growth as an uncountable noun

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns

Hi: Since growth is an uncountable noun is it followed by a plural or singular verb? 
for example,  in this sentence:  Wage and price growth (have or has?) picked up. Should we just have or has?

Answer (score 2):

You could argue that it is the combined growth of wages and prices, and use singular, or that it is two different things, growth of wages and the growth of prices, and use plural.

> But both wage and price growth have slowed over time.

-- Economist Craig James, according to [abc.net.au](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2018-11-01/fact-check-have-wages-grown-steadily-over-the-past-decade/10447492)

> Subdued wage and price growth has forced the BOJ to maintain its massive stimulus

-- article by [Reuters UK](https://uk.reuters.com/article/us-japan-economy-inflation/japan-inflation-ticks-up-but-bojs-target-still-out-of-reach-idUKKCN1M03C6)

A quick search indicates that the plural version seems more common.